# Python: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S21') dtype('S21') dtype('S21')

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes, which both have an `Order ID` and a `date`.

I wanted to add a flag into the first dataframe `df1`: if a record with the same `order id` and `date` is in dataframe `df2`, then add a `Y`:

```
[ df1['R'] = np.where(orders['key'].isin(df2['key']), 'Y', 0)]
```

To accomplish that, I was going to create a key, which would be the concatenation of the `order_id` and `date`, but when I try the following code:

```
df1['key']=df1['Order_ID']+'_'+df1['Date']
```

I get this error

```
ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S21') dtype('S21') dtype('S21')
```

df1 looks like this:

```
Date | Order_ID | other data points ... 
201751 4395674  ...
201762 3487535  ...
```

These are the datatypes:

```
df1.info()
RangeIndex: 157443 entries, 0 to 157442
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Order_ID                                 157429 non-null object
Date                                     157443 non-null int64
...
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 7.2+ MB

df1['Order_ID'].values
array(['782833030', '782834969', '782836416', ..., '783678018',
       '783679806', '783679874'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The problem is that you can't add an object array (containing strings) to a number array, that's just ambiguous:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> pd.Series(['abc', 'def']) + pd.Series([1, 2])
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

You need to explicitly convert your `Dates` to `str`.

I don't know how to do that efficiently in pandas but you can use:

```
df1['key'] = df1['Order_ID'] + '_' + df1['Date'].apply(str)  # .apply(str) is new
```

Comment: `df1['Date'].astype(str)` is more idiomatic and should be faster compared to `df1['Date'].apply(str)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the date data is not a string, you can use this code to change the date to a string and then do the concatenation.

```
df1 =  df1.astype({'Date':'str'})

df1['key']=df1['Order_ID']+'_'+df1['Date']
```

Comment: This has been already suggested in the comment section of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44528113/18145256).