# Python type error (dtype('<U51')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe for which the end output is a concatenation of the cells in a certain order.

Currently my code is as follows

```
debit_creditquestionlist = ('Why is there a ' + df_credit[debit_credit] + ' in ' + df_credit[entity_name] + ' relating to ' + df_credit[account_name] +  ' of ' + df_credit[amount] + ' at ')
```

Currently all are ok except for `df_credit[account_name]` which is the cause of the following error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U51') dtype('<U51') dtype('<U51')
```

I had a look on Stack Overflow and `dtype('<U51')` refers to it being a number.

When I added `str` then it returned every single number rather than the just the single number I require.

Please is someone able to describe how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do:

```
df_credit[account_name].apply(str)
```

that convert each element of the vector into a string variable. Otherwise:

```
 str(df_credit[account_name])
```

is litteraly the conversion of the whole vector into a string, the result you seemed to have obtained.

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527956/python-ufunc-add-did-not-contain-a-loop-with-signature-matching-types-dtype)