# pd.read_html not reading any table from a website

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am trying to extract contained in a table at

https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/netherlands/amsterdam/historic?month=8&year=2018

However, if I try the simple:

```
import pandas as pd
Ds=pd.read_html(r'http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/netherlands/amsterdam/historic?month=8&year=2018')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U82') dtype('<U82') dtype('<U82').
```

I have checked and the table of interest is visible if I look at the html source code,

```
<table id="wt-his" class="zebra tb-wt fw va-m tb-hover sticky-en">
```

how to extract the table using pandas?

Comment: can't recreate on my machine...

Comment: Python 2.7.12, pd.__version__
Out[4]: u'0.20.2'

Comment: oh... I'm using Py3, pandas 0.23.0

Comment: i think there is type problem when its reading the data..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527956/python-ufunc-add-did-not-contain-a-loop-with-signature-matching-types-dtype?rq=1 ...... i would suggest go with request and BeautifulSoup will make the job easier

Answer (score 0):

Not producible, using python3.

Comment: then It might be interesting :)