# TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I would like to pass the `X_train_word2vec` vector as input to `Gensim Word2Vec` model.
The vector type is `numpy.ndarray`, at example:

```
X_train_word2vec[9] = array([   19,     7,     1, 20120,     2,     1,   856,   233,   671,
       1,  1208,  6016,     2,    32,     0,     0,     0,     0, ....)]
```

When I run this code:

```
model_word2vec = models.Word2Vec(X_train_word2vec, size=150, window=9)
model_word2vec.train(X_train_word2vec,total_examples=X_train_word2vec.shape[0], epochs=10)
```

I get this error:

`TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11')`

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527956/python-ufunc-add-did-not-contain-a-loop-with-signature-matching-types-dtype) post, where the issue is due to different data types in the input array but, in my case, I have all the data of the same type: `int`.

**Update:**
The code before `model_Word2Vec`:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)

seq_max_len = 50
X_seq = pad_sequences(sequenza, maxlen=seq_max_len,padding='post',truncating='post',dtype=int)

X_train_word2vec, X_test_word2vec, y_train_word2vec, y_test_word2vec = train_test_split(X_seq, y_cat, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. The error indicates that you have unicode strings in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gensim's `Word2Vec` requires a corpus of texts – such as in its intializer's 1st argument – that's an iterable sequence object of lists-of-string-tokens. It doesn't take a raw numpy array.

Further, if you do supply a corpus at instantiation, as in your line of code...

```
model_word2vec = models.Word2Vec(X_train_word2vec, size=150, window=9)
```

...then it will automatically do its vocabulary-building and training steps. You don't need to then call `train()` explicitly. (And, while it's possible to call `train()` again, very few users doing very advanced things will need to do so. The usual, safe approach is a single training session on a complete corpus, after which the model is "done".)

Finally, `train()` also expects any corpus as an iterable sequence object of lists-of-string-tokens.

If you supply the right kind of corpus, it's doubtful you'll receive an error like you're getting.