# "func 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('S21'), dtype('S21')) -> dtype('S21')" with bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This question might seem to be a duplicate of [Python: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S21') dtype('S21') dtype('S21')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527956/), but the solution presented there isn't working.

I am currently working on https://github.com/executable16/audio-fingerprint-identifying-python and hence I avoided pasting all of the code here. I am getting an error mainly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recognize-from-microphone.py", line 139, in <module>
    matches.extend(find_matches(channel))
  File "recognize-from-microphone.py", line 132, in return_matches
    yield (sid, offset - mapper[hash])
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('S21'), dtype('S21')) -> dtype('S21')
```

In my opinion this exception actually tells very little of what's the actual matter here. I have tried other solutions from SO but they didn't seem to work.

The exact line of error is: `yield (sid, offset - mapper[hash])`.

The types of `sid`, `offset` and `mapper[hash]` are `<class 'int'>`, `<class 'bytes'>`, and `<class 'numpy.int64'>`, respectively.

Any fix to this issue with proper explanation, would be really helpful.

Comment: According to the error message the variables in the subtraction are both arrays with `S21` dtype, i.e. byte strings.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your error with:

```
In [144]: type(b'123')                                                                                 
Out[144]: bytes
In [145]: type(np.int64(3))                                                                            
Out[145]: numpy.int64
In [146]: b'123'-np.int64(3)                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-bd8d8c3ec2cd> in <module>
----> 1 b'123'-np.int64(3)

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('S21'), dtype('S21')) -> dtype('S21')
```

The `np.int64` variable has taken 'control', and converted the `bytes` to array, with `bytestring` dtype being the common dtype.

If the `mapper[hash]` produce a Python number instead we'd get an error like:

```
In [147]: b'123'-3                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-04d1219bd464> in <module>
----> 1 b'123'-3

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'bytes' and 'int'
```

A `bytes` object does not support subtraction.  Only * and +:

```
In [149]: b'123'*3                                                                                     
Out[149]: b'123123123'
```

Converting the `bytes` to number first might solve your problem:

```
In [150]: int(b'123')-np.int64(3)                                                                      
Out[150]: 120
```

Comment: I tried : yield (sid, int(offset) - mapper[hash])


Giving error ->
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xf2\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: That bytestring doesn't represent a number,

Comment: The value of offset where error occurs is : b'S\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' I have no clue what is this value and how to convert this to int.