# ufunc 'add' did not contain loop with matching data types

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a dataframe where some columns has values and some are NaN type (basically float)

This is the dataframe-

[image]

I am looping over the `decribe` and `referring` columns and if that row has some file name, it wil refer to that particular value and populate the dataframe row based on that file name.

This is the code

```
for i in range(0,len(table_names)):
    if type(table_names['referring'][i])!=float:
        a = table_names['referring'][i] #if the referring column row has some value, take that value
        b = table_names['columns'][i]   #take the row name from `columns` column
        a = a + '.xlsx'    #this will make the file name which i need to refer to populate data
        product_name = pd.read_excel(a)  #read the file
        product_name = product_name.values.tolist()
        df[b] = product_name    #populate the particular column with the content of the file we just read
```

If all the values of `referring` and `describe` columns are `NaN`, then I am getting the following error-

```
a = a + '.xlsx'
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('float64'), ftype('<U5')) -> None
```

I referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527956/python-ufunc-add-did-not-contain-a-loop-with-signature-matching-types-dtype) but it shows to change type which I cannot do as it is a file name I am creating.

Comment: try `a = str(a) + ".xls"`.  `a` is a numpy float scalar.  You can't that and a string.  It needs to be a string to do that string join.  But also make sure it isn't a `np.nan`- unless you want 'nan.xlsx'.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But if the column has `NaN` value, it shouldn't enter the if condition. And even if it is entering the if condition, the value of `a` will become `NaN.xlsx'. The logic is, if the column values are NaN, it should skip the if condition.

Comment: @hpaulj, the if condition is failing when all are `NaN` values. Not able to understand if `type(table_names)!=float` is not true, then why it is going inside. Any idea?

Comment: `np.nan` is a float value.  If the whole column is `nan`, the column dtype will be float.  If it has some strings, it will be object dtype. `type...!=float` isn't the correct way of testing for ``nan`.  `pandas` should have some tools for testing cell `type/dtype`.

Comment: If the column is object dtype with some strings than type of a `nan` will be `float` (test is `isinstance`).  But if all nan, then it's `np.float64`.  `isinstance(df[col][0],(float,np.float64))` appears to work for both.

Comment: But see if `df.isna` would be useful